Pandas Map Multiple Columns With A Filter
I have a dataframe like so (simplified for this example)
 Site     LocationName    Resource#    
   01        Test Name            5
   01          Testing            6
   02       California           10
   02            Texas           11
   ...

Each site has their own mapping for LocationName and Resource#
For example:

Site 01 has a mapping of {'Test Name': 'Another Test', 'Testing': 'RandomLocation'} for LocationName and a mapping of {5: 5000} for Resource#
Site 02 has a mapping of {'California': 'CA-123'} for LocationName and a mapping of {10: '10A', 11: '11B'} for Resource#

I am trying to map each respective site with their mappings for the different columns. If the mapping does not exist, I want the field to be None/blank.
My ideal output is:
Site#     LocationName    Resource#    
   01     Another Test         5000
   01   RandomLocation
   02           CA-123          10A
   02                           11B

My idea was to filter for each site and run map on the series
df01 = df[df.Site == '01']
df01 = df['LocationName'].map({'Test Name': 'Another Test', 'Testing': 'RandomLocation'})

But this returns SettingWithCopyWarning since I am performing these operations on a copy.
Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Which of the two lines causes the SettingWithCopyWarning? I would be surprised if the first one does. If not, why is it there?

@MichaelButscher it was the second line.

And why is the first line there?

@MichaelButscher That was just my example to iterate over Site #1 (and using the special mapping meant for Site #1)

I don't get an error on 2.2.0

Yes there is. You can use the map function within the apply method on your dataframe.
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Site': ['01', '01', '02', '02'],
    'LocationName': ['Test Name', 'Testing', 'California', 'Texas'],
    'Resource#': [5, 6, 10, 11]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

mappings = {
    '01': {
        'LocationName': {'Test Name': 'Another Test', 'Testing': 'RandomLocation'},
        'Resource#': {5: '5000', 6: None}  
    },
    '02': {
        'LocationName': {'California': 'CA-123', 'Texas': None},
        'Resource#': {10: '10A', 11: '11B'}
    }
}

def apply_mappings(row):
    site = row['Site']
    if site in mappings:
        location_map = mappings[site]['LocationName']
        row['LocationName'] = location_map.get(row['LocationName'])

        resource_map = mappings[site]['Resource#']
        row['Resource#'] = resource_map.get(row['Resource#'], None)  
    return row

df = df.apply(apply_mappings, axis=1)

print(df)


which gives you your expected output:
  Site    LocationName Resource#
0   01    Another Test      5000
1   01  RandomLocation      None
2   02          CA-123       10A
3   02            None       11B


You can use GroupBy.apply with custom function with Series.map and filtering only matched sites in Series.isin:
d1 = {'LocationName':{'Test Name': 'Another Test', 'Testing': 'RandomLocation'},
      'Resource#': {5: '5000'}}
d2 = {'LocationName':{'California': 'CA-123'},
      'Resource#': {10: '10A', 11: '11B'}}

d = {'01':d1, '02':d2}


def f(x):
    for k, v in d[x.name].items():
        #if possible some mapping key not matched df.columns
        if k in df.columns:
            x[k] = x[k].map(v)
    return x

cols = ['LocationName','Resource#']

m = df['Site'].isin(d.keys())
df.loc[m, cols] = df[m].groupby('Site', group_keys=False)[cols].apply(f)
print (df)
  Site    LocationName Resource#
0   01    Another Test      5000
1   01  RandomLocation       NaN
2   02          CA-123       10A
3   02             NaN       11B

